# Is there any fast way to convert std::vector<std::vector<float>> to std::vector<float2>?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'd like to convert `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` into `std::vector<float2>`. The direct way is like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> pts;
std::vector<float> p1{1.,2.};
std::vector<float> p2{2.,3.};
pts.push_back(p1);
pts.push_back(p2);
std::vector<float2> lattice;
for (auto p : pts){
    p_ = make_float2(p[0],p[1]);
    lattice.push_back(p_);
}
```

Here `float2` is cuda vector types, it is defined like this (not 100% sure):

```
struct __device_builtin__ __align__(8) float2
{
    float x, y ;
};
```

There is any other quick method?

Comment: No, there is no "quick method". Especially since it will be necessary to sanity-check that each component vector always has two values, exactly. The most that can be done is to add a constructor to `float2` that takes a `std::vector<float>` as a parameter. Then you could just use `std::copy`, or use the two-argument version of `std::vector`'s constructor.

Comment: In my case `std::vector<std::vector <float>>` always have two components. I am not sure how data are stored in both cases. If they are the same arrangement in memory, is possible to direct copy?

Comment: No they're not "the same arrangement in memory".

Comment: Is it because `std::vector<float >` is dynamic? my understanding is  `std::vector <float2>` is continuous, is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: The contents of a `std::vector` are continuous, that's correct. However, a `std::vector` itself does not actually contain its contents, they're dynamically allocated. After all `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is a compile-constant. So, while `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` places all of its `std::vector<T>`s in a contiguous memory, each individual `std::vector<T>` dynamically allocates its `T`s independently of all others.

Comment: Thank you for explanation!!!

Comment: If your vector only ever has two elements, consider a `std::array<float, 2>`.

Comment: Definitely I will check for that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. 1 is use a type that means you *know* that there will always be 2 elements, such as:

```
std::vector<std::array<float, 2>>
```

or

```
std::vector<std::pair<float, float>>
```

This will mean you don't need to check that your internal vector is the right size before creating each point for safe code.

Secondly, reserve the right amount of space in your lattice vector before you begin [*emplacing* back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), this will mean that you will never have to resize and you won't waste time copying:

```
std::vector<float2> lattice;
lattice.reserve(pts.size());
for (auto p : pts){
    lattice.emplace_back(make_float2(p[0],p[1]));
}
```

*Note*, this requires that the `float2` structure supports move (which it will based on the definition provided).

If you run a test on these two methods [as done here.](https://ideone.com/37JfqB) You will see that you can heavily reduce the time it will take. In the example that is linked, over 10000 points, the time is roughly 1/5th of the original time with my suggested changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers!!! may I know  under what condition I can use `std::copy` ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean and it seems you are asking about another manner. You should ask a new question if this is the case.